# Removing duplicate URLs in Python including URLs that contain a forward slash

Tags: python, web-scraping, duplicates

The following program is giving me output that includes URLs with and without the forward slash (e.g. ask.census.gov and ask.census.gov/). I need to eliminate one or the other. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as mySoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin as myJoin
from urllib.request import urlopen as myRequest

my_url = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"

# call on packages
html_page = myRequest(my_url)
raw_html = html_page.read()
html_page.close()
page_soup = mySoup(raw_html, "html.parser")

f = open("censusTest.csv", "w")

hyperlinks = page_soup.findAll('a')

set_urls = set()

for checked in hyperlinks:
    found_link = checked.get("href")
    result_set = myJoin(my_url, found_link)
    if result_set and result_set not in set_urls:
        set_urls.add(result_set)
        f.write(str(result_set) + "\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always [right-strip the slash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) - it would be removed if exists and nothing will be done if not:

```
result_set = myJoin(my_url, found_link).rstrip("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_url = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html/"
if my_url[-1:] == '/':
    my_url = my_url[:-1]
```

This snip of code will check to see if the last character in your string is a '/', and if it is, it will delete it.

Good examples of python string manipulation:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/string-manipulation-in-python

Comment: Would not `my_url` become equal to `/` after executing this code?

Comment: alecxe is right, I have fixed my mistake. Thank you